# Bootstrap slide menu navbar-right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some problems achieving my goal on having a sliding menu on the right (instead of left). Is there someone who would be willing to share how to make the nav items including the mobile menu icon and the slide appear on the right side instead of left? In desktop I would like to have the nav items in a navbar-right.

Here is the menu I am trying to change: https://jsbin.com/seqola/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Thanks a lot in advance! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually need to do is just replace every `left` with `right` in the CSS and jQuery.
Working example [here](https://jsbin.com/zacefalowa/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: Thanks alot!! Worked great!